# ActiveRecord has_many where two columns in table A are primary keys in table B

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, has-many

I have a model, `Couple`, which has two columns, `first_person_id` and `second_person_id` and another model, `Person`, whose primary key is `person_id` and has the column `name`

Here's the usage I want:

```
#including 'Person' model for eager loading, this is crucial for me
c = Couple.find(:all, :include => :persons)[0]
puts "#{c.first_person.name} and #{c.second_person.name}"
```

So how can I do this?

Comment: If you're using Rails, why would the primary key on the Person model be "person_id" and not just "id"?

Comment: I changed the names of my models for this post as I'd like to keep the names off the internet. It should be `id` but that's not a difficult fix. Just use `set_primary_key`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The relationships declared in `Couple` should look like this:

```
class Couple
  named_scope :with_people, { :include => [:first_person, :second_person] }
  belongs_to :first_person, :class_name => 'Person'
  belongs_to :second_person, :class_name => 'Person'
end

#usage:
Couple.with_people.first
# => <Couple ... @first_person: <Person ...>, @second_person: <Person ...>>
```

Those in `Person` depend on whether a `Person` can be part of more than one `Couple`. If a `Person` can only belong to one `Couple` and can't be the "first" `Person` on one and the `Second` on another, you might want:

```
class Person
  has_one :couple_as_first_person, :foreign_key => 'first_person_id', :class_name => 'Couple'
  has_one :couple_as_second_person, :foreign_key => 'second_person_id', :class_name => 'Couple'

  def couple
    couple_as_first_person || couple_as_second_person
  end
end
```

If a `Person` can belong to several `Couple`s, and there's no way to tell whether they're the "first" or "second" in any given `Couple`, you might want:

```
class Person
  has_many :couples_as_first_person, :foreign_key => 'first_person_id', :class_name => 'Couple'
  has_many :couples_as_second_person, :foreign_key => 'second_person_id', :class_name => 'Couple'

  def couples
    couples_as_first_person + couples_as_second_person
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a well-written, well thought-out answer. Thanks so much. I'll test this soon and let you know.

Comment: haven't tested it yet, but you WIN :)

Comment: I just did something like this using AREL:

`def widgets;
    Widget.where(
      Wiget.arel_table[:asset1_id].eq(id).or(
        Widget.arel_table[:asset2_id].eq(id)
      )
    );
end`

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but according to the [Rails API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001834), maybe something like:

```
class Couple < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :person, :foreign_key => :first_person_id
    has_one :person, :foreign_key => :second_person_id
end
```

Comment: Those should be belongs_to, not has_one, since the foreign keys are on this model.

Answer (score 0):

Theory only, untested:

Create two subclasses of Person:

```
class FirstPerson < Person
   belongs_to :couple

class SecondPerson < Person
   belongs_to :couple
```

Couple class has_many of each:

```
class Couple
   has_many :first_persons, :foreign_key => :first_person_id
   has_many :second_persons, :foreign_key => :second_person_id
```

Then find:

```
 Couple.all(:include => [:first_persons, :second_persons])
```

Comment: shouldn't a couple `has_one :first_person` and `:second_person`?