# How to show description fields from related table (2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Just started playing with Ruby (no IT background) and restarted the project based on previous question / answer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630906/how-to-show-description-fields-from-related-table)). I have got the following situation now:

created a *currencymaster* table with the following columns `id:integer` , `description:string` and `isocode:string` whereby the ID column is created by Ruby.

created a *currencyrates* table with the following columns `id:integer` , `dominant:integer` and `converted:integer` and  `rate:decimal` whereby the ID column is created by Ruby.

Based on [help on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2125440/activerecord-has-many-where-two-columns-in-table-a-are-primary-keys-in-table-b) I created the following models.
The *models/currencymaster.rb* looks like this:

```
class Currencymaster < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :currency_rates_dominant, :validate => true, :class_name => 'Currencyrate' 
  has_many :currency_rates_converted, :validate => true, :class_name => 'Currencyrate' 
end
```

The models/currencyrate.rb looks like this:

```
class Currencyrate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :currency_master_doms, :class_name => 'Currencymaster' 
  belongs_to :currency_master_convs, :class_name => 'Currencymaster' 
end
```

I haven't changed anything yet in the both controllers.

The *views\currencyrates\index.html.erb* is generated automatically via Ruby and is showing the values of the records as integer. The goal is to show the `currencymaster.iso` value out of the `Currencymaster` table for both `currencyrate.dominant` and `currencyrate.converted`

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your class like this :

```
class Currencyrate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :currency_master_dom, :class_name => 'Currencymaster', :foreign_key => 'dominant' 
  belongs_to :currency_master_conv, :class_name => 'Currencymaster' , :foreign_key => 'converted'
end
```

After that you should do this :

```
rate = Currencyrate.first
rate.currency_master_dom.iso
rate.currency_master_conv.iso
```

All the conventions aren't respected. You should use `dominant_id` and `converted_id` as forign keys, `CurrencyRate` and `CurrencyMaster` for class names and you shouldn't have a 's' whan you use `belongs_to`.

Comment: @ Dougui: thanks again, I will try it and post the code afterwards for checking if you want (please). The class names are created by ruby during the `generate scaffold` statement, can I change them afterwards?

Comment: Yes you can. You can also recreate your code and, when you generate your scaffold, you can add your capitals like this : `rails generate scaffold CurrencyRate ...`. See the guide : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate.

Comment: Now I changed the table `currencyrate` with columns: `id:integer` , `dominant_id:integer` , `converted_id:integer` and `rate:decimal`.

Comment: and the model CurrencyRate like this: `class CurrencyRate < ActiveRecord::Base belongs_to :currency_master_dom, :class_name => 'CurrencyMaster', :foreign_key => 'dominant_id' belongs_to :currency_master_conv, :class_name => 'Currencymaster' , :foreign_key => 'converted_id' end` And the model CurrencyMaster like this: `class CurrencyMaster < ActiveRecord::Base has_many :currency_rate_dominant, :validate => true, :class_name => 'CurrencyRate' has_many :currency_rate_converted, :validate => true, :class_name => 'CurrencyRate' end` Is this ok?